# MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.Grouping package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to compile this project to learn MvvmCross on Xamarin.Android here:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments

In one of the files, I'm missing an assembly for the namespace

`MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.Grouping;`

What nugget package should I download for this?

Comment: You should not need to reference nuget packages directly from the TestProjects in the MvvmCross repository. The TestProjects makes use of project references for all MvvmCross packages. Additionally, there are currently no Nuget stable packages that contain `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.Grouping` as this is a new feature. Try pulling down the latest code or having a look at the [Mvx-Samples](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples) repository.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r, any idea for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728757/markerclick-works-but-infowindowclick-does-not-open-viewmodel