# MarkerClick works but InfoWindowClick does not open ViewModel

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

The following `MarkerClick` implementation works, perfectly fine. I could be able to open other Views via `ShowViewModel`

**View.cs**

```
mMap.MarkerClick += MMap_MarkerClick;

private void MMap_MarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
{
   ViewModel.MapInfoSelected(e.Marker.Title);
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public void MapInfoSelected(string name)
{
    ShowViewModel<StudentViewModel>(new { studentName = name});
}
```

---

`InfoWindowClick` does not trigger to open other View.

**View.cs**

```
mMap.InfoWindowClick += MMap_InfoWindowClick;

private void MMap_InfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
{
  ViewModel.MapInfoSelected(e.Marker.Title);
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public void MapInfoSelected(string name)
{
 // it hits here, but does not hit `StudentViewModel` Init() method, the app is frozen and do nothing
    ShowViewModel<StudentViewModel>(new { studentName = name});
}
```

I even tried the `SetOnInfoWindowClickListener` as follows, it also does not open the View.

```
 mMap.SetOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

 public void OnInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
 {
     ViewModel.MapInfoSelected(marker.Title);
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

It even hits the `OnPause()` method, but still it does not call `StudentViewModel` Init() method if I use `InfoWindowClick` event

```
 public override void OnPause()
 {
   base.OnPause();
   mMap.InfoWindowClick -= MMap_InfoWindowClick;
 }
```

Comment: any output on the log? Mvx is usually verbose, if a ViewModel can't be shown.

Comment: It writes on the output window `Showing ViewModel StudentViewModel` but nothing happens

Comment: It seems me to that there is an internal issue in the `ShowViewModel`, but I do not know how to handle?

Comment: Do you have a small demo project?

Comment: Not actually, at the moment. Is there any sample solution (`mvvmcross`) with couple of fragments that I could able to replicate the issue on it?

Comment: You could install this VS extension (disclaimer; I made it) to spin up a basic app for a repro: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LukePothier.MVXTemplates

Comment: Did you try to use the UIThread to call your ViewModel method?

Comment: mMap.SetOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
or
mMap.InfoWindowClick += MMap_InfoWindowClick;

Have you tried to do it inside OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)?
(and of course, IOnMapReadyCallback for your MapFragment )

Comment: @casillas it does sound like something is wrong in your view. In the code-behind of that page, if you have InitializeComponent(). Wrap it in a try catch. The catch should hit if there is a problem with the UI and give you the error in question

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate`, 
put `mViewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<YOUR STUFF>>(){`  and in the `.observe` put the `init()` method, that is what works for me