# Call MarkerClick Method

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I wonder how I could able to call  `MMap_MarkerClick` from  `MMap_InfoWindowClick`?

```
private void MMap_InfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
{
     //call MMap_MarkerClick

}

private void MMap_MarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
{
   ViewModel.MapMarkerSelected(e.Marker.Title);
}
```

I am trying to achive it, because `MMap_InfoWindowClick` does not open new ViewModel, but `MMap_MarkerClick` does. [MarkerClick works but InfoWindowClick does not open ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728757/markerclick-works-but-infowindowclick-does-not-open-viewmodel)

Comment: you can just call "MMap_MarkerClick(sender, null);" but somehow I doubt this addresses your underlying issue.

Comment: @Jason, but if I send null, how could able to get `e.Marker.Title`?

Comment: construct a new MarkerClickEventArgs and pass it in.  Or just call ViewModel.MapMarkerSelected directly from InfoWindowClick?

Comment: even though I call it, it still same issue, cannot able to open the `ViewModel`, it does not underlying my issue.

Comment: what do you mean by "open ViewModel"?  A ViewModel is just a class, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Jason I am referring to my linked (previous) question. `ShowViewModel` actually opens a `View` in `MVVMCross`. It opens when I use `MarkerClick`, but it does not when I use `InfoWindowClick`

Comment: this question is not tagged MVVMCross

Comment: @Jason, I have added the tag.